# Source Maps on Bundled Meteor Application

Tags: coffeescript, meteor

Is there a way to enable coffeescript source maps for a bundled meteor application?  I am trying to debug some behavior that is appearing in the bundled app that is not in the development app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.